# Access and addition of two elements of integer array in bash

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I could not access elements from the integer array in bash and add the two.

This is my code:

```
popA[$n]=${popA[$n]} - ${popA[($n)-1]};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are accessing the elements correctly, but you need an arithmetic expression to actually perform math:

```
popA[$n]=$(( ${popA[$n]} - ${popA[$n - 1]} ))
```

In case you are wondering why you don't need `$((...))` for the `n-1` index, the array subscript is automatically evaluated as an arithmetic expression for an indexed array. (The parentheses around `$n` are unnecessary, although harmless.)